# Mobaxterm text editor

Tags: text-editors, tabs, mobaxterm

I use mobaxterm to connect via ssh. I would like to about the tab sizes in the Mobaxterm text editor. I would like to increase the size of each tab to view the whole file title. Is that possible?

Thanks, Dimitris